# Do nouns in simple apposition semantically unpack to predicate nominatives in English?

Tags: english, semantics, grammar, cross-linguistic

A Koine Greek grammar states that nouns in simple apposition are semantically understood as predicate nominatives.

So,  "Paul the apostle" unpacks to "Paul is the apostle" and  "the apostle is Paul" and is a reciprocating proposition.

The grammarian says:

> The appositive functions very much like a PN in a convertible proposition— that is, it refers to the same thing as the first noun. The difference, however, is that a PN makes an assertion about the S (an equative verb is either stated or implied); with appositives there is assumption, not assertion (no verb is in mind).

Does English work this way as well?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "unpacking", which is just the Conduit Metaphor. Certainly appositives, like relative clauses, are presupposed, so one could conclude that Paul was the apostle from an appositive _Paul the apostle_; but that's not the same thing as asserting that sentence, and what's said versus what's taken for granted is rather the problem in translating ancient texts.

Comment: I have only seen it affect the translation when the verb must be supplied for an English rendering.  In that case it is a verbless clause which is common in Greek but not English.   It sounds like simple apposition is not language specific by your explanation.   Thanks.

Comment: And many languages don't have a copula so there might be no written difference between an apposition and a copular sentence. There probly would be in speech, though.

Comment: @jlawler   I added more from that grammarians explanation.

Comment: That's approximately what I said, except I used the technical term [_presupposition_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/506503/15299) instead of the more vague _assumption_

Comment: @jlawler   Yes, I understand.   It seems like this transcends a particular language and is related to logic?

Comment: Again, more or less. Presuppositions are part of Pragmatics, which is about context and how it provides most of our understanding; Pragmatics expands on Semantics, which is in fact [related to logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), but much more complex.

Comment: @jlawler I have been looking for something like in your paper!   Thank you!  I need to digest it.   It looks like a systematic way to diagram a sentence and much more.

Comment: Well, the [Verb Phrase Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), which follows the logic guide, goes into that.

Comment: @jlawler  I've got lots of reading to do!   Thank you.  The grammarian I quoted is Daniel Wallace.  Have you heard of that Greek professor?